# Set Multiple Environmental Variables On Invocation of Rake Task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rake-task

I can invoke a Rake task and set a single environmental variable like this:

```
$ ONE=1 rake temp:both
```

But how do I set two environmental variables?

This doesn't work:

```
 $ ONE=1 TWO=2 rake temp:both
```

This works, but is confusing to read:

```
$ ONE=1 rake temp:both TWO=2
```

**How can I pass more than one env before the call to `rake`?**

Comment: ```ONE=1 TWO=2 ruby -e 'puts ENV["ONE"]; puts ENV["TWO"]'``` works for me (also with ```rake```), in bash and in zsh (gnome-term).

Comment: What does `temp:both` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agree with @Ernest; it should work.  Here's a sample...

Sample rake task to echo vars:

```
task :echo_env do
  puts "VAR1: #{ENV['VAR1']}"
  puts "VAR2: #{ENV['VAR2']}"
end
```

Execute task:

```
VAR1=first VAR2=second bundle exec rake echo_env
```

Output:

```
VAR1: first
VAR2: second
```

Comment: One of the envs I was passing in was `RAILS_ENV`. This was switching the environment and making a Rake task included in a Gem that was in the development group unavailable, causing error.